# How can I trigger autocomplete when a text is pasted in the input field

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I am triggering autocomplete function when a user types into an input text field. I want to trigger it on pasting the text in input field. How can I do that?

Comment: bind onchange event to detect change if someone paste any characters